# Server is not acknowledging httpPost header in Android app

Tags: android, json, header, http-post

I am trying to make an Android app that uses web services and I have successfully used HttpGet. I'm trying to use HttpPost now but I'm not doing one of the headers correctly. Here is my code:

```
//Auth token post request
HttpPost getToken = new HttpPost(tokenURI);
getToken.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
getToken.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

//Create token JSON request
String jsonRequest = new JSONStringer().object().key("auth")....toString();         
StringEntity se = new StringEntity("JSON: " + jsonRequest);
se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"));
se.setContentType("application/json");
getToken.setEntity(se);
```

The response I am getting is this: "error":"Expecting to find application/json in Content-Type header..." and it tells me that the request is malformed or incorrect so it can't be processed.I am confused because I explicity added the header to getToken. What am I doing wrong here? Let me know if there is any more detail I can add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the formatting I was using was not the expected format.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but you are setting twice the Content-type, on `getToken` and on `se`, is that normal?
Have you tried removing one?
Also, I usually use `setHeader` instead of `addHeader`, not sure it is making any difference...

Comment: Yes I have tried using only and I have tried bot set and add for the header. I did not have the getToken headers before I tried the request the first time and the error is what prompted me to put those in.